# How to replace the values of a Variable to a sample data in a textarea in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

So I have a textarea, I could get the ff. values in the text area.

```
Good morning $firstName $lastName. The date today is $date
```

How do a replace the variables $firstName $lastName and $date with a sample data stored in a variable of my component. i.e

```
$firstName = "John"
$lastName = "Doe"
$date = "October 23, 2019"
```

and make it have a final output of

```
Good morning John Doe. The date today is October 23, 2019.
```

.....

Could this be achhieve using angular features. How do I do this in typescript ?

I do however have an idea how to implement this in javascript, just not in a Typescript.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Interpolation` like this:

```
<textarea rows="4" cols="50">
Good morning {{$firstName}} {{$lastName}}. The date today is {{$date}}
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Template Literals backticks (``)

```
const output = `Good morning ${$firstName} ${$lastName}. The date today is ${$date}`
```

Read documentation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Answer (score 0):

Template literals are string literals allowing embedded expressions
In component,

```
tempalte = `Good morning ${$firstName} ${$lastName}. The date today is ${$date}`
```

In html you can add

```
<textarea [(ngModel)]='tempalte '></textarea>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xmejbs[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xmejbs)

Comment: I'm not yet familiar with the templating in angular. So I'm confused. So, how do I make sure that the variables are exchanged with the proper sample data that is encoded in the typescript file/component?.

Comment: data is two-way bind between html and component. If you set any value in the component, that value will be available in html so, vise Versa.

Comment: Can you show a live working example of this?. I can't quite grasp how this works stil and how it gets the values of the variable in the typescript file.